# Track foreign url using google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a URL(https://www.mysite.com/tab/subtab/) that belongs to my website(https://www.mysite.com/). Clearly, to track clicks on this url, all I have to do is append the utm_source, utm_medium and utm_campaign parameters to it. 
Now, what I want to do is, track a url http://www.notmysite.com/tab/subtab/. This url is neither a part of my site, nor is it mentioned any where in my google analytics account, only the link is available for modification. If I append the utm_* params here, the "clicks" information goes to the http://www.notmysite.com website owner's GAQ account and not mine(obviously!). What parameters should be appended to this foreign url, so that I can track the clicks on it?
If this is not possible with google analytics, are there any other options?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into event tracking to track clicks on links.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Anatomy

Taking an example from Google's doc:

```
<a href="http://www.notmysite.com/" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Link', 'Click', 'Not My Site']);" target="_blank">Click here</a>
```

Any clicks on that link will now appear in Analytics under Content -> Events. Notice though how I added target="_blank" which is needed for ensure the accuracy of events for external links due to there not being enough time to send the data to Google. A workaround is to add a delay via javascript which is a better approach if you're tracking more clicks.

Comment: Let me be more clear about what I am trying to achieve here. An application on my website(`https://www.mysite.com`) posts links of other websites(for eg: `http://notmysite.com/tab/subtab`) on facebook pages. Now the link `<a href="http://www.notmysite.com/" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Link', 'Click', 'Not My Site']);" target="_blank">Click here</a>` as you said, is supposed to go on a `facebook page`. How will the "_gaq" object be accessible there? If a `fb` user clicks on this link, wont the browser throw up an err warning, `_gaq not defined`, coz the scope is limited to only my site?

Comment: Is there a way to access the user's google analytics information using an api key/oauth?